# need to execute the python script at time of shutdown

Tags: linux, rc

I have created python script and want to run it at time of shutdown.

I have saved the script in `/etc/init.d` and created a soft link for it in the `rc0.d` directory, but the script is not working.

I am able to run the same script manually but it is not executed at time of shutdown.

Comment: Is it "not working" in any particular way (error messages?), or is it just not executing?

Comment: i mean to say the script is not executed when system shutdown

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the softlink into `rcX.d` where `X` is the runstate you are in, and is generally 3.

You need to name the softlink `KXXyyyyy`, where `K` stands for "kill", `XX` is a two digit number that specifies the order the scripts are run during shutdown, and `yyyyy` is arbitrary but is by convention the name of the script the softlink points to.

Comment: I have palced the script in the init.d location and when we need to run the script i have created the same situation but not able to run that script when we check that script manually if we run the script it is working fine but if we place.

Comment: @Kusalananda  placed the script in the init.d location and when we need to run the script i have created the soft link (K00zabbix_remove.py) situation but not able to run the script and when we run  that script manually it is working fine.

Comment: @StephenRauch, that last comment is not for me but for you.